# How do I verify that my Ingress-nginx Controller is intercepting the traffic going into my Minikube LB Services (local)?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am working on a mini project where my spring boot application is hosted into a Minikube cluster with a K8s Service (LoadBalancer) that exposes it to other app within the app. I can confirm that the web application and the k8s service are both working by running `minikube tunnel` on command line to "port forward" the exposed service to my localhost.

Now, I want to explore how I can put an Ingress controller in front of the K8s Service. I installed the Ingress-ngnix controller with `minikube addons enable ingress` and it's installed successfully and it is also running. To test whether traffic actually goes through the Ingress Controller, i still have to run `minikube tunnel`. This is the confusing part: how do I know if the Ingress Controller is actually doing its job? I can send request to my web app without Ingress Controller as well.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Check for services and pods in the namespace 'ingress-nginx':

kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc,po

You should find a svc delivering traffic to a pod 'controller'.

The controller pod handles the ingress rules.

Comment: Yea I can verify that it is running:`pod/ingress-nginx-controller-5f66978484-4r8qk RUNNING` but how do I check if it is indeed intercepting and directing traffic to the my web app's LB k8s Service?

Comment: Did you locate the Service that delivers traffic to controller? Send your requests to that Service instead. Then inspect the controller pod logs: kubectl -n ingress-nginx logs ingress-nginx-controller-5f66978484-4r8qk

Comment: I did: `NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.105.188.95   <none>        80:30549/TCP,443:32762/TCP   48s`. But the problem is that regardless of having an ingress controller or not, i am making the call to the same url `localhost:80` (port 80 is what my LB service exposes the web service to). So I guess I don't get what you mean by "send traffic to that ingress service".

Comment: Make the call to that service instead at address 10.105.188.95:30549